# Redirect a cron job to another url

Tags: php, redirect, cron, wget

I have a PHP file that contains a META Refresh/Redirect at the end of file to another PHP file.
I try to wget the file as URL in cron job.  Example: wget http://www.domain.com/file.php
and the cron job works fine, But redirection doesn't work.
my file.php contains something like this:

```
Some Codes
...
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="5; URL=http://www.domain.com/file2.php" >
```

How can i redirect a cron job from current URL using wget to another URL ?

Thanks.

Comment: wget wont follow a redirect outside the original domain

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I try to use my file to refresh itself for some processing reasons. for example: file.php?i=1-15 , which 15 times refresh itself, i dont know how cron job can do this for me

Comment: any one of the php loops would be a million times better approach

Comment: i know that , i said for SOME REASONS i need to use this approach, how can i do it.

Comment: explain the reasons and I'll give you a better alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an HTTP redirect response, not a meta refresh.

```
<?php
http_response_code(302);    // 302 Found; PHP >= 5.4 only
header("Location: /file2.php");
```

These will only function correctly if no output has been sent yet, so you want them at the very beginning of your script.  If you MUST wait until the end, you can use "ob_start()" to buffer output until the end, THEN send the response code and headers, and finally use "echo ob_get_clean()" to send the buffered content.

Comment: It should be noted, this approach will not have any delay between redirects.